# List of default modules that come along with python 2.x installation

Tags: python, python-module

I have a project in my mind, for which i am planning to use python for implementation.

Before I start, i am looking for a comprehensive list of all modules which come with a standard python2.x (python2.7) installation so that I can figure out what all can be done without installing a single dependency and later add dependencies accordingly according to the needs.

Is there any online list available or any other way to find this list.

Comment: Please **update** your question to explain why the Python documentation isn't the first place you looked.

Comment: @S.Lott: basically i use Google for all my queries. Google dint gave me a valid result for this question. PS: i directly hit to python documentations when i need to get through a module. dint know that entire list is already documented.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the docs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Python 2.7 library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html) has a list, and with documentation of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the list of all python modules is to type following at prompt:

```
help("modules")
```

Comment: This is the answer to a different question. He wants to know the modules that are installed by default, not the list of all modules that are currently installed on that particular PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of modules for a default Python 2.7 intallation in the [Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html) section of the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/).

Links are provided for the last 2.x version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

[Python 2.7 Global Module Index](https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/modindex.html

Is this what your locking for?

Brgds,
Trollchen

Comment: 404: The requested URL /modindex.html was not found on this server.